# Force direct layout with filter in Vega

Tags: networking, visualization, interactive, vega-lite, vega

I'm using Vega to visualize networks interactively.

I would like to apply interactive node filtering in my visualization.

[In this case](https://vega.github.io/editor/#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), I have attempted to filter nodes from a large dataset based on the "Nodes_TopN" value. Although the first plot appears correctly, the subsequent plots either fail to appear or display incorrect data.

Answer (score 1):

The following will correctly limit the number of visible nodes.

[Link](https://vega.github.io/editor/#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)

Unfortunately, I think there is a bug with the linkpath *require* property (or at least I never got it to work). I have documented the issue and the work around [here.](https://github.com/vega/vega/issues/3557)